# Determination of the last three digits of $2014^{2014}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

May I know if my proof is correct?

Consider $x$ such that $2014^{2014} \equiv x  \pmod{1000}.$

By Euler's theorem, $2014^{\ \psi(1000)} =2014^{\ \psi(2^3)\psi(5^3)}=2014^{400}\equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$.

It follows that $2014^{2000} \equiv 1  \pmod{1000},$ hence   $2014^{\ 14} \equiv x \pmod{1000}.$

By Binomial expansion, $2014^{\ 14} = 14^{\ 14}+2000m$, for some positive integer $m$.

Finally$, 14^{14} \equiv x \pmod{1000} \Longleftrightarrow \ x= 16$ and the last three digits are $016.$

In general, could we use  the above method to determine the exact value of $n^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} ?$

Thank you and wish you a successful 2014!

Comment: If $2014^{400}=1 (\bmod 1000)$, then it is odd.

Comment: $n^{\varphi(x)} \equiv 1 \pmod x$ if and only if $ \gcd(x,n)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), Euler's [totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) theorem and Fermat's [little](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) theorem need $(a,m)=1$  for $a^n\equiv1\pmod m$ where $n$ may have different values in each case.

But $(2014,1000)=2>1$

As $\displaystyle1000=8\cdot125$

Clearly, $\displaystyle2014^{2014}\equiv0\pmod{2^3}\  \ \  \ (1)$

As $2014\equiv14\pmod{125},\displaystyle 2014^{2014}\equiv14^{2014}\pmod{125}$

As $\phi(125)=100, 2014\equiv14\pmod{100};\displaystyle 14^{2014}\equiv14^{14}\pmod{125}$

Now, $14^{14}=2^{14}\cdot7^{14}$

and $\displaystyle2^7=128\equiv3\pmod{125}\implies 2^{14}\equiv3^2\equiv9$

$\displaystyle7^{14}=(7^2)^7=(50-1)^7\equiv-1+\binom7150\pmod{125}\equiv99$

$\displaystyle\implies 14^{14}\equiv99\cdot9\pmod{125}\equiv16\ \ \ \ (2)$

Now apply the famous [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(2)$

Comment: Thank you. May I know why $2014^{2014} \equiv 14^{14} \ (\text{mod} 125)?$ How does it follow from my original argument?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo, you have found $$2014^{2014}\equiv14^{14}\pmod{2000}$$ As $125$ divides $2000,$  $$2014^{2014}\equiv14^{14}\pmod{125}$$

Comment: I think I have found $2014^{14} \equiv 14^{14} \ (\text{mod 2000})$ instead.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo, same logic can be applied as $125$ divides $2000$ as well

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get how it follows that $2014^{2014} \equiv 14^{14} \ (\text{mod} \ 2000).$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo, You have written "$2014^{\ 14} = 14^{\ 14}+2000m$" right? Now see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: Thank you but I'm afraid it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12242/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-alexy-vincenzo)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct because you have to treat the moduli $8$ and $125$ separately (because $8$ and $2014$ are not relatively prime), and use (a very simple case of) the Chinese remainder theorem to deduce the answer. If you do so, you will see that it does not change your result ($16$). Also, you should write $\varphi$ instead of $\psi$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I thought if $a,b$ are co-prime, then $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)?$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo It is true that it is multiplicative, but the Euler-Fermat theorem that you used is only true if the base is coprime to the modulus.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly apply Euler's theorem because $\,2104\,$ is not coprime to your modulus $\,1000.\,$ But your argument is quickly patched. It shows that $\, n := 2014^{2014}\!\equiv 16\pmod {125}$ and, since $\,8\mid n,\,$ also $\,n\equiv 16\pmod 8\,$ thus $\,n \equiv 16\,$ mod lcm $\!(8,25) = 8\cdot 125 = 1000.$

Comment: Thank you. How we know $2014^{2014} \equiv 16 \ (\text{mod} \ 125)?$

Comment: @Alexy Euler's Phi Theorem applies here, so you can proceed as you did in your question.

Comment: Using that theorem, I obtain $2014^{200} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} 125)$ and hence $2014^{2014} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} 125)$

Comment: But $\,14^{14}\!\equiv 16\pmod {125}\,$ so you have an error somewhere.

Comment: I see. By Euler phi theorem, we get $2014^{100} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 125)$

Comment: @Alexy Right, you original approach works fine modulo $125,\,$ using $\,\phi(125) = 100$.

Comment: But how do I get $2014^{2014} \equiv 16 \ (\text{mod 125})$ from here?

Comment: @Alexy One way to finish is to calculate $\,14^{14}\pmod{125},\,$ e.g. by repeated squaring.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I don't get you.

Comment: @Alexy Where, *precisely* are you stuck?

Comment: What you mean by 'repeated squaring'?

Comment: See e.g. [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) A search on MSE will turn up many examples.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the last $n$ digits necessarily implies $\pmod{10^n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer

You have already found $$2014^{2014}\equiv14^{14}\pmod{2000}\implies2014^{2014}\equiv14^{14}\pmod{1000}$$

Now as $\displaystyle14^{14}=2^{14}\cdot7^{14}$ and $(14^{14},1000)=8=2^3$

Let us find $\displaystyle2^{14-3}\cdot7^{14}\pmod{\frac{1000}{2^3}}\implies 2^{11}\cdot7^{14}\pmod{125}$

From my other answer, $\displaystyle7^{14}\equiv99\pmod{125}$

and $\displaystyle2^7=128\equiv3\pmod{125}\implies2^{11}\equiv2^4\cdot3\equiv48\pmod{125}$

$\displaystyle\implies 2^{11}\cdot7^{14}\equiv48\cdot99$
$\displaystyle=(50-2)(100-1)=5000-50-200+2\equiv2\pmod{125}$

Now as $\displaystyle a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod{m\cdot c}$ where $a,b,m,c$ are integers

$\displaystyle\implies 2^{11}\cdot7^{14}\cdot8\equiv2\cdot8\pmod{125\cdot8}$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo, please find my other method here