# Formulae of the Year 2016

Tags: limits

Decode the following limits to welcome the new year!

This is my love limits (Created by me). I hope you Love it.

Let $$A_{n}=\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}$$
show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^4\left\{\dfrac{1}{24}-n\left[n\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-A_{n}\right)-\dfrac{1}{4}\right]\right\}}=2016$$

can you create some nice other problem (result is 2016)? Happy New  Year To  Everyone .

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2?lq=1

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,It's different my limits.But Thank you

Comment: I see that $\lim A_n=\pi/4$.

Comment: ... because $A_n$ is a Riemann sum?

Comment: Is the limit of $n(n(\pi /4 - A_n)-1/4))$ 1/24?

Comment: I think it has to be, otherwise the 'global' limit would be infinite or $0$.

Comment: May be before that it has to be proved that $n(\pi/4-A_n) \to 1/4$.

Comment: My idea was to evaluate the remainder between the integral and the Riemann sum, piece by piece, computing

$$\arctan((k+1)/n)-\arctan((k)/n)-n/(n^2+k^2)$$

Comment: Hmm... looks like it is the $6^{th}$ term in an [Euler-Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) of the integral.
$$\frac{1}{2016} = \frac{B_6}{6!}\left[\frac{d^5}{dx^5}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]_0^1$$

Comment: 2016=1*14*144...;D.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
A_{n} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{n \over n^{2} + k^{2}} =
\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 - n\ic} =
\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 - n\ic} -
{1 \over k + n + 1 - n\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 1 - n\ic} - \Psi\pars{1 - n\ic}}\,,\qquad\qquad
\pars{~\Psi\ \mbox{is the}\ Digamma\ Function~}.
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
A_{n} & =
\Im\braces{\Psi\pars{\bracks{1 - \ic}n} + {1 \over \pars{1 - \ic}n}
- \Psi\pars{-n\ic} - {1 \over -n\ic}}\quad\pars{~Recursion~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2n} +
\Im\braces{\Psi\pars{\bracks{1 - \ic}n} - \Psi\pars{-n\ic}}
\end{align}

---

The [Digamma Function Asymptotic Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)  is given by
\begin{align}
\Psi\pars{z} & \sim
\ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{B_{2n} \over 2n\,z^{2n}} =
\ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 12 z^{2}} + {1 \over 120z^{4}} -
{1 \over 252z^{6}} + \cdots
\\[5mm] & \pars{~z \to \infty\ \mbox{in}\ \verts{\,\mathrm{arg}\pars{z}} < \pi~}
\,,\qquad B_{k}\ \mbox{is a Bernoulli Number.}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\Im\Psi\pars{\bracks{1 - \ic}n} & \sim
-\,{\pi \over 4} - {1 \over 4n} - {1 \over 24n^{2}} +
{1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{6}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
\Im\Psi\pars{-n\ic} & \sim
-\,{\pi \over 2} - {1 \over 2n}  + \cdots
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
A_{n} &\ \sim\ {\pi \over 4} - {1 \over 4n} - {1 \over 24n^{2}} + {1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{6}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
n\pars{{\pi \over 4} - A_{n}} &\ \sim\
{1 \over 4} + {1 \over 24n} - {1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{5}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
n\pars{{\pi \over 4} - A_{n}} - {1 \over 4} &\ \sim\
{1 \over 24n} - {1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{5}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
n\bracks{n\pars{{\pi \over 4} - A_{n}} - {1 \over 4}} &\ \sim\
{1 \over 24} - {1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{4}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
{1 \over 24} - n\bracks{n\pars{{\pi \over 4} - A_{n}} - {1 \over 4}} &\ \sim\
{1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}\,n^{4}} + \cdots
\\[5mm]
n^{4}\braces{%
{1 \over 24} - n\bracks{n\pars{{\pi \over 4} - A_{n}} - {1 \over 4}}} &\ \sim\
{1 \over \color{#f00}{2016}} +
\pars{~\mbox{terms of order}\ {1 \over n^{2}}~} 
\end{align}

---

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad%
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over
n^{4}\braces{%
1/24 - n\bracks{n\pars{\pi/4 - A_{n}} - 1/4}}}} = \color{#f00}{2016}
\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$